# adding animation to displaying images, fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: ios, swift, animation, nstimer, banner

someone help me!
error occurs here
`let newBanner = UIImageView(frame: self.bannerImageView.frame)`
and the error only occurs when I switch the homepage to and back from other views frequently

```
func sheduleBanner(){
    let timeInterval: NSTimeInterval = 3
    bannerTimer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(timeInterval, target: self, selector: "updateBanner", userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
    bannerTimer.fire()
}

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    sheduleBanner()
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
    bannerTimer.invalidate()
}

func updateBanner(){
    let animationInterval = 0.5
    let userDefault = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        var baseImageName: String!
    if let lastBanner = userDefault.objectForKey("lastBanner") as? Int {
        baseImageName = "banner\((lastBanner+1)%3)"
        userDefault.setObject((lastBanner+1)%3, forKey: "lastBanner")
    } else { //should never happen
        baseImageName = "banner0"
        userDefault.setObject(0, forKey: "lastBanner")
    }

    let newBanner = UIImageView(frame: self.bannerImageView.frame)
    newBanner.imageForRemoteFile(baseImageName)

    UIView.transitionFromView(bannerImageView, toView: newBanner, duration: animationInterval, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.TransitionFlipFromRight){ finished in
        if finished {
            self.bannerImageView = newBanner
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you try just updating the `imageForRemoteFile` instead of the entire `UIImageView`? They both have the same `frame` anyways.

Comment: @Caleb Do you mean just use `self.bannerImageView.image = newBanner.image`. I will give it a shoot and keep U updated.

Comment: @Caleb It cannot work. If I just update the image, the imageView is not animating and the images don't change at all

Comment: Maybe`self.bannerImageView.imageForRemoteFile(baseImageName)` inside the animation?

Comment: You can wrap everything under let new banner into an if let statement to ensure the values aren't nil.

Comment: @Caleb I don't think that will happen. If I get the image from server, the imageView may be empty. I will give it a try

Comment: @Caleb Good point, let me try it out

Comment: the `UIImageView(frame:)` method will not produce optional, I will check the       imageView's property and try it out

Comment: @thefredelement Yes, I have done that. But unfortunately the imageBannerView still will become nil which stops the animation.

Comment: @Roger then storing the image view as a property on self

Comment: @thefredelement I have done that too, but I cannot figure it out too, I forget what kind of error I did come into.

Comment: Is self.bannerImageView.frame correctly hooked up in your .nib/.storyboard?

Comment: @BellAppLab Yes, it is.